# Boundary value problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunctions $y_n(x)$ for the equation $y''+\lambda y=0$ in the case that $y(0)=0$ and $y(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$.

I am not sure as to how to approach this problem and would appreciate some help.

Comment: (Hint) All you need to do is solve the differential equation. Each $\lambda$ will give a different solution but observe only certain $\lambda$ will work. Think about the initial conditions, and how the constrains $\lambda$

Comment: @JonathanDavidson In my textbook it says that only $\lambda>0$ will work, but I don't understand why that is.

Comment: Two upvotes for a question outsourcing the OP's homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda < 0$ and define $\mu^2 = -\lambda > 0$. The differential equation can be rewritten as $y'' = \mu^2y$. The general solution is then $$y = c_1e^{\mu x}+c_2e^{-\mu x}$$ However, to satisfy the initial values, it turns out that both the constants must be $0$ yielding only a trivial solution. Hence, $\lambda >0$. Again we set $\lambda =\mu^2$, and we obtain the solution $$y = c_1\sin(\mu x)+c_2\cos(\mu x)$$ In order to satisfy the initial conditions, we must have $c_2 = 0$ and $\sin(\mu \pi/2) = 0$. This implies $$\frac{\mu \pi}{2} = n\pi, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$ Hence, $\mu = 2n$ for any natural number $n$. Therefore, $\lambda_n = 4n^2$.